# Set maxzoom and minzoom property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set maxzoom and minzoom property - because when I click zoomin button the text become bigger and bigger so I want to set a maxzoom and minzoom property in my jquery code.

My html code and jquery code are below.

The reset button works perfectly but when I went on click the zoomin and zoomout button the text gets bigger and bigger and in zoomout property the text gets smaller and smaller ... so I want to set maxzoom and minzoom property.

```
<button class="zoomIn">Zoom In</button>
<button class="zoomOff">Reset</button>
<button class="zoomOut">Zoom Out</button>enter code here

<script>
  $('.open-book').css({
    // 'position' : 'absolute',
    'top' : '0px',
    'left' : '0px',
    'height' : $('.outboard').height(),
    'width' : $('.outboard').width()
  });

  var currZoom = 1;

  $(".zoomIn").click(function(){

    currZoom+=0.1;

    $('.open-book').css({
      // 'position' : 'absolute',
      // 'top' : '45px',
      // 'left' : '20px',
      // 'height' : $(window).height()-65,
      // 'width' : $(window).width()-40,
      'zoom' : currZoom
    });
  });
  $(".zoomOff").click(function(){

    currZoom=1;

    $(".open-book").css({
      // 'position' : 'absolute',
      // 'top' : '45px',
      // 'left' : '20px',
      // 'height' : $(window).height()-65,
      // 'width' : $(window).width()-40,
      'zoom' : currZoom
    });
  });
  $(".zoomOut").click(function(){

    currZoom-=0.1;

    $('.open-book').css({
      // 'position' : 'absolute',
      // 'top' : '45px',
      // 'left' : '20px',
      // 'height' : $(window).height()-65,
      // 'width' : $(window).width()-40,
      'zoom' : currZoom
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain what difficulty you're having?  You don't appear to have attempted to limit the zoom.  A check after increasing would probably suffice in the first instance `if (currZoom > 2) currZoom = 2` (there are many other ways to do this)

Comment: i want to set minZoom and  maxZoom property on my jquery code .. because i wnt to restrict the zoomIn and zoomOut property ..  actually the problem i am having is if i went on to click  zoomIn  button the text gets bigger and bigger and  if i went on to click zoomOut button the text become smaller and smaller .. so i wnt to restrict that with minZoom and  maxZoom property .please put this two property on my coade and send it to me .. am i clear ?

Comment: Mention your `minZoom` & `maxZoom` values.

Comment: You're clear in describing your *requirement* - ie what you want to do (and simply restating exactly what's already in the question won't make the requirement "clearer").  You're not clear on why you can't do this.   Or where you expect this "property" to appear.

Comment: @ Asfan Shaikh my maxzoom value will be 4 and minzoom value will be 1 ... plz put this on may code and send it to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define `minZoom` and `maxZoom` values and compare with `currZoom`. Compare values by wrapping in `if` condition and change element `CSS`.

**Try this code.**

```
<button class="zoomIn">Zoom In</button>
<button class="zoomOff">Reset</button>
<button class="zoomOut">Zoom Out</button>enter code here

<script>
  $('.open-book').css({
    // 'position' : 'absolute',
    'top' : '0px',
    'left' : '0px',
    'height' : $('.outboard').height(),
    'width' : $('.outboard').width()
  });

  var currZoom = 1;
  var minZoom = 1;
  var maxZoom = 2;

  $(".zoomIn").click(function(){

    if(maxZoom >= currZoom){
      currZoom+=0.1;
      $('.open-book').css({
        // 'position' : 'absolute',
        // 'top' : '45px',
        // 'left' : '20px',
        // 'height' : $(window).height()-65,
        // 'width' : $(window).width()-40,
        'zoom' : currZoom
      });
    }

  });
  $(".zoomOff").click(function(){

    currZoom=1;

    $(".open-book").css({
      // 'position' : 'absolute',
      // 'top' : '45px',
      // 'left' : '20px',
      // 'height' : $(window).height()-65,
      // 'width' : $(window).width()-40,
      'zoom' : currZoom
    });
  });
  $(".zoomOut").click(function(){

    if(minZoom <= currZoom){
      currZoom-=0.1;
      $('.open-book').css({
        // 'position' : 'absolute',
        // 'top' : '45px',
        // 'left' : '20px',
        // 'height' : $(window).height()-65,
        // 'width' : $(window).width()-40,
        'zoom' : currZoom
      });
    }

  });
</script>
```